# Return top level elements from list based on position

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to generate a table with pagination by using XPath.

Here's an example of two items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:data xmlns:d="defiant-namespace" d:constr="Array" d:mi="114">
    <d:item d:mi="24">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="13">/Partition/MYLB1</name>
        <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="14">1.1.1.1</ip>
        <port d:constr="String" d:mi="15">80</port>
        <pools d:constr="null"/>
        <loadbalancer d:constr="String" d:mi="23">LB1</loadbalancer>
    </d:item>
    <d:item d:mi="51">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="25">/Partition/MYLB2</name>
        <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="26">2.2.2.2</ip>
        <port d:constr="String" d:mi="27">443</port>
        <pools d:mi="47" d:type="ArrayItem">
            <name d:constr="String" d:mi="46">myPool</name>
        </pools>
        <loadbalancer d:constr="String" d:mi="50">LB2</loadbalancer>
    </d:item>
    <d:item d:mi="24">
        <name d:constr="String" d:mi="13">/Partition/MYLB1</name>
        <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="14">1.1.1.1</ip>
        <port d:constr="String" d:mi="15">80</port>
        <pools d:constr="null"/>
        <loadbalancer d:constr="String" d:mi="23">LB1</loadbalancer>
    </d:item>       
</d:data>
```

Let's say I only want the first two items in this list, how do I accomplish that?

Managed to do it with this query:

```
//*[name][position() <= 1]
```

However, I suspect that if I add more children later and one of them has the attribute "name" it would also be affected.

This is what I figured would work, but it's returning a lot of items where I would only expect one:

```
//*[position() <= 1]
```

I've searched for how to match only the first level of children, how to get the position of an array. But in each thread that turned up they knew which value they searched for whereas I just want to return the elements independently of their content or number of ancestors.

An explanation of how I am thinking wrong and how to do it right would be much appreciated!

---

**2016-01-05 - Edit:** Revising the example with a lower level having "name" in it.

Also adding an example:

I need the xpath to only return the top level items:

Ie:

```
<d:item d:mi="24">
    <name d:constr="String" d:mi="13">/Partition/MYLB1</name>
    <ip d:constr="String" d:mi="14">1.1.1.1</ip>
    <port d:constr="String" d:mi="15">80</port>
    <pools d:constr="null"/>
    <loadbalancer d:constr="String" d:mi="23">LB1</loadbalancer>
</d:item>
```

But not:

```
<name d:constr="String" d:mi="46">myPool</name>
```

/Patrik

Comment: Can you please show desired result?

Comment: Example has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//*[position() <= 1]` will match each first child of any parent element. If you want to match just `<d:item d:mi="12">` and `<d:item d:mi="24">`, no matter how much elements you will add to parent element in the future, you should use

```
//*[name][position() <= 2]
```

These `XPath` should be more suitable:

```
//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name][position() <= 2]

//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name()="d:item"][position() <= 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however, this also returns lover level items with "name" in them. I have updated the example  to show what I mean.

Comment: Got your point. You need this `'//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name][position() <= 2]`. This will match only direct child of `<d:data>`. And this `'//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name()="d:item"][position() <= 2]` exact child (`<d:item>`)

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! Please update your answer and I'll mark it as the right one. Hopefully if helps someone else one day? I still don't get why `//*[name][position() <= 2]` matches deeper into the xml while `//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name][position() <= 2]` does not though?

Comment: Updated. This `//*[name][position() <= 2]` means that you want to find each element in `DOM` which has **attribute** `name` and it is first or second child of its parent (nameless parent) while `//*[name()="d:data"]/*[name][position() <= 2]` intend to find direct child with attribute `name` of parent **with name** `d:data`